# Use threads during iteration

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

There is a collection and each element of that collection is sent to a function where 5 threads have to work on it.

How to make 5 threads work on the passed item?

```
foreach(var item in collection)
{
   doSomeWork(item);
}

void doSomeWork(object item)
{
   //here i have to do something with the passed 'item' by using 5 threads
}
```

Comment: What version of C# are you using? This can easily be done using the parallel extensions.

Comment: @trnTrash: explain why you need 5 threads exactly? What logic/processes are those 5 things? Why not use .NET's built in parallelization? Let the compiler figure out the best way.

Comment: Threads don't "work on things". They are 'places' where code can run in 'parallel'. It may sound like I'm being pedantic, but there is the posibility that half your problem is that you're trying to solve the wrong "problem"! You don't have 5 threads that need to work on the item, you have 5 objects that need to work on the item. Before you even begin to consider whether these 5 objects can be allowed to work on the items in parallel, you need to know whether any of them will be changing the state of the item.

Comment: @craig I am not used working with threading, that's where the big gap comes from

Comment: No problem. Hopefully, my comment gets you thinking about the problem differently, which may lead to a better solution. In my experience, many people decide to use threading because they _"think it will make their application run faster"_ ... However, if this is done without understanding the intricacies of multi-threading, the resulting application is usually: less stable, far more complicated to maintain, and even quite a bit **slower** !!! As mentioned in my previous comment, the most important question is: Can any of the objects working on the item make any changes to it?

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (var item in collection)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(doSomeWork, item);
    }
}
```

Comment: In such case I got an error that the job on a certain file cannot be done because another process is using that file.

Comment: What file are you talking about? You didn't mention anything like this in your question. You asked how to run 5 threads for each item in a given collection and I answered it. It is quite obvious that you cannot write to the same file from different threads/processes.

Answer (score 1):

In .NET 4 you can use Parallel LINQ:

```
Parallel.ForEach(collection, item => {
  // process each item
});
```

this will use the Parallel Extension's (PFX) heuristics to schedule one or more workers from the thread pool.

Comment: It's net 3.5, unfortunately :(

Comment: i think you mean fortunately ??